# Get value of parameters in deep link url iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, deeplink

everyone.
My question is: How can I get data from deep link URL?
I have two apps and I want to send data from app1 to app2 using the deep link.
I have a button on app1 to click and open app2 then app 2 will get data from app1 by deep link URL.

Here is my code of button send in app1:

```
@IBAction func btnSend_Clicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let text = self.txtInput.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "myapp://?code=\(text!)")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

so, How can i get data from deeplink url (code parameter) in app2?

Really Thanks for your help !!!!

Comment: where is your deeplink code on app2

Comment: I don't know how to write that code.

Comment: add the below code in your app2 and add the URL schema **myapp** in your app2 plist

Comment: @Anbu.Karthk I alread added. I just want to know the code to get value from deeplink parameter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You implement this code in Appdelegate:

```
 func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        let urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
        let items = (urlComponents?.queryItems)! as [NSURLQueryItem]
        if (url.scheme == "myapp") {
            var vcTitle = ""
            if let _ = items.first, let propertyName = items.first?.name, let propertyValue = items.first?.value {
                vcTitle = url.query!//"propertyName"
               }
        }
        return false
   }
```