# Using IOS built-in QRCode scanner with custom url schemes

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, qr-code

I am working on a prototype to test a concept for iOS using QRCodes.

iOS has integrated QRCode detection within their Camera.app. I have created an app with a custom URL scheme, and generated a url code with that scheme:

e.g. myApp://some-message?someParam=1

My hope was that I could simply generate several QR codes with different parameters to trigger different parts of my app experience.

I have things mostly working. The scheme is detected, and the QR code successfully launches the app, but I can't find any documentation on how to capture the URL itself so that I can extract the parameter I passed in through the URL.

If I manually type the URL into safari, it detects fine with [open(_:options:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open), but fails if I try the same exact URL as a QR code using the camera app's built in reader.

I'm looking for any tips at this point? :-)

Comment: In what way does it fail after scanning a QR code with your app's custom URL?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44580936/3241041) to get the parameter from the deep link?

Comment: @rmaddy - I scan the QR code, I get a notification to open my App, but when the app opens, I never get an event handing me the url back.  UIApplication’s open event is what I believe is supposed to hand this back to me, but it never fires if I open the app with a QR Code.

Comment: I think you have the wrong method. You need to implement the UIApplicationDelegate method `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool`. That will be called.

Comment: An under iOS 13, the UISceneDelegate method `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>)` will be called instead.